# How to edit footer?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am searching for a piece of html which I believe may be causing my site to be obstructed by random black boxes on every page.

I believe that  footer is somehow duplicated and `<footer></footer>` may be the root cause but unsure where to locate it or if there's such a thing as article.php?

Example page: https://adsler.co.uk/events/

Comment: You can look as follows: single.php, loop.php, footer.php, archive.php, index.php inside of your current active WordPress theme.

Comment: Checked all except for loop.php which I don't have...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your content entry has footers. It is not the page footer it is the entry footer that you are seeing. It might be weird to change if you are using a theme. There might be a setting to remove entry footers. But if that does not work you can go into your CSS and apply `.entry-footer { display: none; }`. This will remove the black box. I will attach a screenshot.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise that you leave the footer in the article alone. Fix your problem by styling `.site-footer` instead of `footer`

The `footer` element existing in more than one place is semantically correct HTML5. It signals users and devices of all types that this is the footer of the current part of the site. Your black boxes are because you have styles applied to `footer` that should be applied to `.site-footer` instead. You can't predict that the html content created by some plugin wont include a `footer` element, but you can be fairly certain that it won't have a `footer` with the class `.site-footer`

Comment: Thanks. Solved using footer.entry-footer {display: none;} that should cause me too many probs should it?

Comment: That code should be okay. If this page is the only spot you are seeing the boxes, and the .entry footer has no content - no problem. Just be on the lookout in the future that more footers can appear as content is added.